# Different websocket libraries communications between each other

Tags: python, android, docker, websocket, socket.io

I have no idea on how to google this one, so therefore i must post the question here.

Ok, so firstly I have an websocket server up and running on my ubuntu server in digital ocean cloud.

I am using python with the "FastAPI" : https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/

and my code is as simple as this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Chat</h1>
        <form action="" onsubmit="sendMessage(event)">
            <input type="text" id="messageText" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <ul id='messages'>
        </ul>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                var messages = document.getElementById('messages')
                var message = document.createElement('li')
                var content = document.createTextNode(event.data)
                message.appendChild(content)
                messages.appendChild(message)
            };
            function sendMessage(event) {
                var input = document.getElementById("messageText")
                ws.send(input.value)
                input.value = ''
                event.preventDefault()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
"""


@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(html)


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    print("somebody entered the server!")
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {data}")
```

and then i deploy it using docker following this link : https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/
Everything seems to be working fine and i can read live messages in terminal.

So here are the issues:

When i try to connect to the websocket server using this site: http://websocket.org/echo.html

I get this message in the CMD: `http://websocket.org/echo.html('78.158.237.146',%2061139)%20-%20%22WebSocket%20/%22%20403`

which indicates that it connects some way and thats good.

So then I try connecting to it through the "websocket tester app" in android, the error I get on the ANDROID PHONE is: `Expected HTTP 101 response but was 403 forbidden`

on the server(ubuntu terminal) i get the message:  `('78.158.237.146', 48389) - "WebSocket /" 403`

And over TO THE MOST IMPORTANT THING:

I have an android app with "socketio" library in it, here is my code for that :

```
      import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class WebSocketClass extends Application {



    public static final String THE_SOCKET_SERVER_URL =  "http://ip-adress-to-server:5080/";

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(THE_SOCKET_SERVER_URL);
            //Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Connected to server!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //mSocket.emit("android-device", "Android device connected to the server!");

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {

        return mSocket;
    }

}
```

and THEN this gets printed in the ubuntu terminal:

```
INFO:     78.158.237.146:49433 - "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

So obsiously, my question is: How can i connect to my "fast-api webserver" on ubuntu from my android phone that is using socketio library? Is this possible or does all the devices/platforms need to use the same library?

Fastapi websocket framwork in python is preferred because it is easy and good to use, and socketIO library for Android is easy to use there.

Could someone help me solve this issue?